# modifying class private variable using reference variable

Tags: c++, c++11

I was playing with reference variable. And I learned that I am able to directly modify class private variable from outside of class using its reference.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define print(x) cout<<x<<endl;

class prison
{
private:
    int victim;

public:
    prison(int ele)
    {
        victim = ele;                       
    }

    int & lophol()
    {
        return victim;    
    }

    void info()
    {
        print(victim)
    }
};

int main()
{
    prison sam{0};
    int &culprit = sam.lophol();
    culprit++;
    culprit++;
    sam.info();
}
Output:
$$ g++ -std=c++11 exp.cpp && ./a.out 
2
```

I can access private variable via reference.
Is this behavior OK?

Comment: this behavior is ok however this is not considered as a good practice

Comment: When you put a public function `int& lophol() { return victim; }` into your class, the compiler assumes you know what you're doing.  The member functions of a class are trusted to access private variables and have presumably been written by someone who understands the abstraction the class is trying to enforce.  If that's not the case, all hope is lost anyway O_o.

Comment: There is legality in term of language specification and then there is good design...

Answer (score 1):

Technically, accessing a private variable through a reference works - even from outside the class. However, keep in mind that leaking a reference to a private variable to the outside world is in conflict with the idea of "private". Read the [section about minimizing exposure to members in the C++ Core Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-private) for some reasons why you want to keep members private.